# Pass shell output to groovy variable

Tags: groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I try to pass output from shell script to groovy script:

```
job {
  steps {
    systemGroovyCommand ("""
...
def parseJiraIssue() {
    def process = '/bin/bash -x -c source \$JENKINS_HOME/jira.sh && jira_get_info \$ISSUE'.execute()
    process.waitFor()
    def result = process.text
    println("Output: " + result)
    return result
}
String info=parseJiraIssue()
"""
    )
  }
}
```

but I get empty result.
Everything is ok, with:

```
job {
  steps {
    shell(''' source \$JENKINS_HOME/jira.sh && jira_get_info \$ISSUE ''')
  }
}
```

but in this way I can't pass my shell output to groovy variable. I also tried:

```
def parseJiraIssue() {
    def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
    def process = '/bin/bash -x -c source \$JENKINS_HOME/jira.sh && jira_get_info \$ISSUE'.execute()
    process.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
    process.waitFor()
    println("Output:" +  sout + ", \nERROR:" +  serr)
```

but the same result. I get Output and error empty

Comment: maybe you have information in STDERR stream? `process.text` returns only STDOUT...

Comment: better to use `waitForProcessOutput(Appendable output, Appendable error)` instead of  `consumeProcessOutput` and `waitFor`

Comment: Never ever use `"string".execute()` - always use `["string","string",...].execute()`. Something along the lines will split at whitespace if you use the initial one and you most likely would see an error from bash, that the arguments make no sense.